# Disable auto focus in dialog- modal in Angular 9/ material

Tags: modal-dialog, autofocus

I'm using dialog from angular material-9.

The problem is: I can't disable auto focus when modal-dialog is opened in browser.

I tried with tab index and with auto focus in other input-field it doesn't work

I'm using Angular 9 for my code. I tried to use markasuntouched afterviewInit, but I still have the same problem !!

Even tried restoreFocus but still facing same problem